# Show only specific categories in permalinks for pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to ask this question in the Wordpress Devlopment network with no success, I'm trying to display specific category only in permalinks for pages.

Right now the permalinks structure (POST Type) for All pages and post

`example.com/the-post-title/`

this is work for all my categories of post and pages and i want this for all categories look like
but i want this category 'downloads' when i select on those pages its show look like

`example.com/downloads/the-post-title/`

anyone help me out how to do it with php code or something else for this specific categories.

i try some plugin and search on web but not found anythinf related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to define a custom rewrite rule, to capture requests to `/downloads/` and direct them correctly. To do so, use [`add_rewite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) to match the existing rewrite rule for posts and pages.

Then use [the `post_link` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/) to change the post's URL to include `/downloads`/.

Pseudo-code:

```php
add_action( 'init', static function () {
    add_rewrite_rule( ... );
} );

add_filter( 'post_link', static function ( $permalink, $post ) {
    // add test for post is in category
    return sprintf( '/downloads/%s', $post->post_name );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/link/ this plugin for customizing your link.